# Addition operator not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, operators, addition

Addition operator isn't working for me in Javascript. If I do 5+5, it gives me 55 instead of 10. How can I fix this?

```
var numberOne = prompt (Enter first number.);
if (numberOne > 0.00001) {
 var numberTwo = prompt(Enter the second number.);
if (numberTwo > 0.00001) {
var alertAnswer = alert (numberOne + numberTwo);
}
}
```

Comment: `parseInt()`, they are not numbers but strings

Answer (score 4):

You're reading in strings, and concatenating them. You need to convert them to integers with `parseInt`.

IE:

```
var numberOne = parseInt(prompt("Enter first number."), 10);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was just wondering what that number 10 does. Thanks.

Comment: @EpicGamer757 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 0):

There are two main changes that need to take place.  First, the prompts must use `String`s.  Second, you must parse the user's `String` input to a number.

```
var numberOne = prompt ("Enter first number.");
if (numberOne > 0.00001) {
     var numberTwo = prompt("Enter the second number.");
if (numberTwo > 0.00001) {
    var alertAnswer = alert (parseInt(numberOne,10) + parseInt(numberTwo,10));
}
```

Comment: Too early to omit radix

Comment: @zerkms I assumed the op was using a decimal based number system.

Comment: how would JS know that if you don't specify that explicitly?

Comment: Isn't that the default?

Comment: @zerkms Your right.  `An integer that represents the radix of the above mentioned string. Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified.`

Comment: it will be in further ES iirc, that's why "too early"

Answer (score 0):

you need to use parseInt

as in

```
 var a = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: a potential problem with `parseInt()` (in some situations) is that it accepts garbage at the *end* of a numeric string. That is, if I enter "123abc", `parseInt()` will happily return `123` as the result.  Also, of course, it just handles integers — if you need floating-point numbers (numbers with fractional parts), you'll want `parseFloat()`.

An alternative is to apply the unary `+` operator to a string:

```
 var numeric = + someString;
```

That will interpret the string as a floating-point number, and it *will* pay attention to trailing garbage and generate a `NaN` result if it's there.  Another similar approach is to use the bitwise "or" operator `|` with `0`:

```
var numeric = someString | 0;
```

That gives you an integer (32 bits).  Finally, there's the `Number` constructor:

```
var numeric = Number( someString );
```

Also allows fractions, and dislikes garbage.